# how to use string as function in dart?

Tags: android, ios, flutter, dart, listview

> I am stuck in a situation where i need double doller function like in
> php.  like:

```
var citis = [];
```

> i want to use :

```
citis = ServiceList.mycity();
```

instead :

```
if(mycity = 'Delhi') { citis = ServiceList.Delhi();  } else
if(mycity = 'Mumbai') { citis = ServiceList.Mumbai();  }
```

> i am sure that is possible but how, can anyone help?? Thanks in
> advance.

Comment: Dart does not have this kind of dynamic invocations since that would make it impossible to know for sure which methods is actually being used when Dart are doing optimizations as part of the compiling of your code (since strings can be built at runtime). Are you in control of `ServiceList`? If so, you could make a `Map` where the key is your city name and value is the value you want. You can then lookup your value in this map.

Answer (score 0):

If it were JavaScript, you could have the string: `"ServiceList." + mycity + "()"` and then executed it using eval function.

Use the [Dart Eval](https://pub.dev/packages/dart_eval) package to accomplish the same thing in Dart. Take the `ServiceList.mycity()` function as a string and replace `mycity` with whichever city you want. Then, evaluate it using the package.

Comment: Dart Eval is to complex and i tried a lot, no avail.

Answer (score 0):

One thing you can try is to put all the cities and locations in an Key/Value Array in ServiceList and the function ServiceList.cities($city) .e.g ServiceList.cities('Mumbai') or ServiceList.cities('Delhi')